# Refreshing div after clicking on save

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have two div's in my layout. Where in the left div I have written by form and in the right div there is a table.

After clicking on save button, only my right div where the table is present must be refreshed. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
//This is my **Left div**, Where i need to enter the **values** and when I click on **save** button, All the values must be displayed in the **right div** and that **right div must be refreshed**


<div align="left"> 
  
  <div id="bundle_number_text_label"> Bundle Number </div>
  <input id="bundlenumber" style=" padding: 3px 0;" type="text" name="bundle_number"  /><br />
  

  <div id="date_text_label"> Date </div>
<input type="text" style=" padding: 3px 0;" id="date" READONLY/><br/>




 <div id="length_text_label"> Length </div>
 <input id= "length" style=" padding: 3px 0;" type="text"  name="Length" /> (in mm)

 

 <input type="radio" name="browser" value="number" checked>
 <label><?=lang('number_txt')?></label>
    <input type="radio" name="browser" value="Balance"/>
    <label><?=lang('balance_txt')?></label></br>
 <input id= "rate" style=" padding: 3px 0;" type="text"  name="Rate" />
 
 <input type="button" value="Save" name="Save" id="save_id">
 
 </div>
```

This is my **right div** and after clicking on **save button**, all the values must be displayed here and this div has to be refreshed.

```
<div id="div_save" align="left">  
 <table align="center !important" width="80%"  border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <th>Select</th>&nbsp;
  <th>Bundle Number</th>&nbsp
  <th>Date</th>&nbsp;
  <th>Length(mm)</th>&nbsp;
  <th>Numbers</th>
  <th style="display:none;">Party id</th>
 </tr>
 
   <tr>
   <td align="center" valign="top">  
  <input type="radio" /></td> 
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td>   
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td>   
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td>  
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td> 
 </tr>
   
    <tr>
   <td align="center" valign="top">  
  <input type="radio" /></td> 
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td>   
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td>   
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td>  
  <td align="center" valign="top"></td> 
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: refreshed means??? post some of your code, we cant help with so less information

Comment: ok. edited the code. can you please helpme now?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two or three fashionable ways:

You can move the content of everything you want to be refreshed into an external file and use the `<iframe>` tag to update that specific frame only, or

You can use Ajax to refresh only the desired html sections, like in this example: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_example.asp.

But perhaps the most easiest way is to take advantage of jQuery power. In jQuery you can do this like so:

```
$('#first_div').load('test.html', function() {
  alert('Loading completed.'); //callback function
});
```

Comment: +1 for linking to a relevant tutorial as well as providing a brief example.  But I don't think using iframes is very "fashionable" anymore.

Comment: Perhaps you should show how to **save** with jQuery, since that is a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

use `$('#the_one_div').load('source.html');` to reload content of the div in button click() event.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to provide some support on your server side to render only your table.

Then, just do

```
var submittedData = $('#myForm').serialize(); 
$('#myTable').load('http://www.example.com/myPage?renderTable', submittedData);
```

The more advanced version would get a json string, and create the table client side.

Answer (score 0):

you can used Ajax for this type of requirement

Answer (score 0):

POST the form via AJAX, using jQuery.

```
var formData = $('#MyForm').serialize();
$.post( 'url-to-POST-to.html', 
    formData,
    function(data){
        $('#div_save').html( data);
    }
);
```

On success, the div with that ID will have it's contents replaced by whatever the server sends back in response to your POST.

PS:  Where's your FORM tag in the left div?

Answer (score 0):

using Ajax function you can reload the page

```
function Onsave(context){
    var eventArgs = context.getEventArgs();
    if (eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 1) {

        window.location.reload(true);
```